# Having an issue with records and tuples in SML

Tags: tuples, sml, records, smlnj

I am trying to solve an exercise in SML like ;

Write an ML program to be used for a multiple choice exam containing 10 questions. Your program should include the following:

o     The answer key of the exam
     e.g.

```
  val key= “adabcbaadb”;
```

o    Type definition for a record (info) which contains name and answers of a student.
     e.g. `{name=”Ali”,ans=”abadccdadb”}`

o    Type definition for a tuple (result) which contains name and score of a student.
e.g. `("Ali",60)`

o   Write as many functions as needed to take a list of records of type info containing the information of 3 students, calculate their scores, and convert them into a list of tuples of type result. You can write other supporting functions as well

e.g.

```
-  val stuInfo:info list=[{name=”Ali”,ans=”abadccdadb”},
                             {name=”Ege”,ans=”cbbdacabda”},
                             {name=”Can”,ans=”adabcbaadb”}];

        - val results = calculate(stuInfo);
 val results = [("Ali",60),("Ege",20),("Can",100)] : result list
```

o    Write as many functions as needed to calculate the average score, and return the students who received a score above the average.
      e.g.

```
-val aboveList=aboveAvg(results);
       val aboveList = [("Ali",60),("Can",100)] : result list
```

Notes:
   Make sure you give the types of your parameters and return value in all your functions.
   Paranthesize your expressions.
   Use explode function which converts a string to a character array
         e.g.

```
 - explode "abc";
        val it = [#"a",#"b",#"c"] : char list
```

My written code for this exercise is below ; but my code is not working :/ Where is my mistake ?

```
val answer_key="ddacbadbca";
type student_information={s_name:string,s_choice:string};
type student_result=string*int;
val student:info list=[{s_name="David",s_choice="adcbbaccad"},{s_name="John",s_choice="ccdabdbbcc"},{s_name="Alice",s_choice="abdaccacdb"}];
val 3studentsResult:student_result=average(student_information);
fun average ((h::t):student_information list):student_result list=student_score(explode"#ans h",explode"key")::average(t);
val sum=0;
fun student_score(((a::b,c::d):'a list):'a list) = (if(a=c) then sum=sum+10 else sum=sum+0 )::student_score(b,d);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues about this code. Before starting, I should recommend you to work on your styling, you can use some spaces and extra lines between functions to see what you are doing easily, like this:

```
val answer_key = "ddacbadbca";

type student_information = {s_name:string, s_choice:string};
type student_result = string * int;

val student : student_information list =
  [{s_name="David", s_choice="adcbbaccad"},
   {s_name="John",  s_choice="ccdabdbbcc"},
   {s_name="Alice", s_choice="abdaccacdb"}];
```

You might also want to keep your variable and type names consistent. I think the convention is to use snake case (like `snake_case`) for type names and camel case (like `camelCase`) for variable and function names.

Here are some of your actual mistakes:

For your `student` variable, you give the type `info list`, which doesn't exist in your program. I assume your `student_information` variable used to be named `info`, so you should change one of those to the other.

You have a variable named `3studentsResult`. Variables cannot start with numbers, they have to start with letters. You have to rename that variable, to something like `threeStudentsResult`.

In your `3studentsResult` variable, you are using the `average` function that you define later. That doesn't work in Standard ML. You should define a function before using it. (Unless you need mutual recursion, you can use the `and` keyword then, but it's irrelevant to your problem.) Therefore, define `average` before `3studentsResult`, and define `student_score` before `average`.

Even after fixing these, your `student_score` function is incorrect. I assume `sum=sum+10` means that you are trying to change `sum`'s value, like you would do in an imperative programming language. However, Standard ML is a functional language and changing values of variables is something you should avoid in functional programming. In fact, when I talk about "variables" in SML, I mean value declarations that cannot be changed. I recommend you to think about your problem a little bit more and maybe you can divide your problem into sub-problems. Good luck.